# How to get reference to the only datatable in the active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding a new row to the table I have in the active sheet using the following method:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyDataTable1").ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
```

The problem is that it is dependent on the table name "MyDataTable1". If I change the active sheet to the one in which the name of table is "MyDataTable2", I have to change my code too. Is there anyway to find the table in the active sheet automatically so that I do not need to change the code every time I switch between the sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one table per sheet than use

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
```

to retrieve the name of the first table in the ListObjects collection.